# Allow disabling all the annoying popovers on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability

Today I tried to look up a question on Stack Overflow. I had *two* popovers on the page, one inviting me to take a short survey (which didn't even load!) and one inviting me to learn how the review queue works.

In addition, the GDPR cookie consent dialog doesn't seem to remember its settings, and reappears periodically. Perhaps it's using the old "only remember the setting properly if it was 'Accept All'" dark pattern?

This visual clutter makes the site less usable. Please don't keep going down the road of "every other site spams people with popovers so it's OK for us to do it". It's not.

There should be an easy way to turn off all this intrusive rubbish and just show the question, the answers, the answer box, and the linked/related/hot network questions — and this method should be configurable even when logged out (if I'm linked to an SE site I don't normally participate in, I shouldn't have to log in just to have a usable experience).

Ideally, every site would be a subdomain of stackexchange.com so people could set **one** set of overrides in a custom stylesheet, or configure their adblockers **once**, and the work needed at the SE end would be to continue not using randomly-generated class names and IDs in the CSS. But I don't suppose there's much appetite for moving SO to stackoverflow.stackexchange.com :)